# Node.js TLSwrap.onread ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js

So basically I have created my own "Imgur" where I enter a image URL etc.

```
https://images.hdsydsvenskan.se/980x588/Q2GO5t2lmKtW6WwGuEVQNTPmt4o.jpg
```

The issue is that it worked before but now I am getting errors (And I haven't change the code at all - My guess that it has to do with some URLS?) that are saying:

```
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'}
```

and honestly I don't see issue because it does work on other pictures but if I choose etc the one below. It keeps giving me that issue.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const request = require('request')
const express = require('express')


const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8888

// Path to images directory
const images = path.join(__dirname, 'images')

// JSON parsing middleware
app.use(express.json())


app.post('/newimage', (req, res) => {
  const imageUrl = req.body.image_url
  const imageName = req.body.image_name
  request({
    url: imageUrl,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
    }
  })
  .on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(res.status())
    res.status(500)
    res.send('not ok')
  })
  .on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(`Response for ${imageUrl}`)
    console.log(response.statusCode + '\n')
    res.send('ok')
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(images, imageName + '.png')))
})


app.get('/images/:imagename', (req, res) => {
  const imageName = req.params.imagename
  const filePath = path.join(images, imageName + '.png')
  console.log(imageName)
  console.log(filePath)
  if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .pipe(res)
  } else {
    res.send('No image found')
  }
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`)
  console.log(`http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:${PORT}`)
})
```

If anyone has any clue how I can solve it! I would appreciate it!

Comment: How did you set up HTTPS? Are you using a SSL terminator? Could that be causing the connect reset? Does the server work if you connect directly to it with HTTP?

Comment: I have setup on a Google Server. Basically if I take another site lets say `https://assets.caliroots.com/images/499021/large/bow3ry-x-caliroots-long-sleeve-tee-vit.jpg` and I send that to the script. It works fine. Like it process the image and everything. But if I try the link etc. `https://www.adidas.se/dis/dw/image/v2/aagl_prd/on/demandware.static/Sites-adidas-SE-Site/Sites-adidas-products/sv_SE/v1543971196008/zoom/F36641_01_standard.jpg?sw=60&sh=60&sm=fit` then im getting that error. The reason is unknown for me but it works otherwise perfectly fine for other pages. @DanD.

Comment: You also have directory transversal issue in that you don't check that imageName does not contain .. or / so this server can be made to overwrite any writable file.

Comment: Im just using random name that is given by uuid4 which means the chanes are very slim to get hit with the same Name I believe.

Comment: I would make the server generate the UUID rather than giving it a filename then when the post succeeds the URL of the image is returned in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something funky going on with the Adidas-server that you mention [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631718/node-js-tlswrap-onread-econnreset#comment94123336_53631718), it requires a particular list of headers to be set before it works (requests time out for me otherwise):

```
request({
  url: imageUrl,
  headers: {
    Accept: '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
  }
})
```

It looks like the Varnish cache that they're using might be misconfigured (or it's some strange attempt to try and block scrapers).

Comment: Oh that was the solution. I didn't thought that the headers actually does that much! Thanks alot Robert!